# Has LinkedIn removed companySizes, industries and seniorities from company follower statistics available via the API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using the LinkedIn REST API to access the company-statistics dataset used to provide "companySizes", "industries" and "seniorities" arrays within the returned data. These have disappeared very recently (customer notified us of missing data 24 hours ago) - has LinkedIn removed this data, and if so, is there a workaround method of retrieving it?

Currently trying to access via `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{company_id}/company-statistics?oath2_access_token={access_token}&format=json`

Getting a response back, but there's a whole ton of data that's missing now.

Any ideas?